# how to use dynamic data-title using ng-repeat in angular ng-table?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've searched the whole web on how to make the following work:

```
<td ng-repeat="dynamicObject in [4,5,6]" dir="ltr" data-title="dynamicObject" class="sam_td">
    {{dynamicObject}}
</td>
```

The problem is that `dynamicObject` is not parsed at the `data-title`.
I've seen many questions like that with no definite answer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What are you aiming to do with data-title? Why are you for instance assigning a title to the string "dynamicObject"?

Comment: You probably want to get the value of `dynamicObject` - then you need to use `data-title="{{dynamicObject}}"` - this will interpolate the expression and produce a string value

Comment: Hi, I tried with data-title="{{dynamicObject}}" at the before posting this question. It doesn't work. I get Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'dynamicObject' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{dynamicObject}}] starting at [dynamicObject}}]

Comment: Hi Wayne,please do not mind the logic in the code, it is just an example of a simple scenario that doesn't work. I'm struggling with populating the data-title attribute with a dynamic var from ng-repeat iteration